# Trouble with getting and then changing the state in react using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to basically change the state of my app using redux when the toggle button is clicked. The onClick method seems to be working with the log statements I have showing that the onClick is working. It doesn't seem like I am able to get the state and therefore is not allowing me to change the state.

Can you tell me how I can get the state and then change the state?

Here is my code:

```
export default function (state=[], action) {
      switch(action.type) {
        case 'TOGGLE_EXPAND_CALENDAR_SECTION':
          console.log("case 'TOGGLE_EXPAND_CALENDAR_SECTION'");
          if (action.payload.moduleSizeCalendar == 'dashSection') {
           console.log("click worked if");
        return {
          ...state,
          moduleExpandImageCalendar: 'img/collapseBlue.png',
          moduleSizeSchools: 'hidden',
          moduleSizeCalendar: 'dashSectionFullScreen',
          moduleSizeStudent: 'hidden',
          moduleSizeTeacher: 'hidden',
          moduleSizeClasses: 'hidden',
          moduleSizeTasks: 'hidden',
          moduleSizePhotos: 'hidden'
        }
      } else {
           console.log("click worked else");
        return {
          ...state,
          moduleExpandImageCalendar: 'img/enlargeBlue.png',
          moduleSizeSchools: 'dashSection',
          moduleSizeCalendar: 'dashSection',
          moduleSizeStudent: 'dashSection',
          moduleSizeTeacher: 'dashSection',
          moduleSizeClasses: 'dashSection',
          moduleSizeTasks: 'dashSection',
          moduleSizePhotos: 'topLine'
        }
      }
  default:
  return {
      ...state
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You state has a default value of empty array but you're treating it like an object in the reducers. Not sure if that's the problem you're facing but you should fix that.

I highly suggest using redux dev tools which will really help understand what your actions and reducers are doing and what the current state actually is.